# What is a Flexible Array?

Tags: language-agnostic

What is a Flexible Array, exactly?
I can't find much on it.

Comment: Language-Agnostic question, trying to understand the differences between Static/Dynamic/Flexible arrays.

Comment: @rlb.usa - "Flexible" arrays don't exist, but a "flexible array member" is very specific to C (and C++ but no one uses it there).

Comment: Please provide a link or a quote or a reference.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: not even in C++, really. If you define a a struct with its last element an array (typically of size 1), you can *probably* get away with allocating more memory, and accessing it via larger indexes into that array -- but officially, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jerry - "Flexible array member" refers to the canonized version adopted in C99, but the hacky technique you described has been used under C89 (and possibly early C++) for years.

Comment: @Chris: yes, it's been in use (to varying degrees), but before C99, it had undefined behavior. In C++, it still does, and as far as I can see, it will under C++ 0x as well.

Comment: Flexible vs Static vs Dynamic Arrays is a topic in my Programming Languages course but I didn't understand what Flexible was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flexible array is an array whose index bounds are determined at run time and may change during the lifetime of the array.

Java arrays are flexible. For example, in Java you can assign one array to another:

```
int[] a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] a2 = {1, 2, 3};
a1 = a2;
```

At first, a1 has index range 0–3, and a2 has index range 0–2.

After the assignment a1 = a2, a1 points to an array with index range 0–2, so the index range of a1 varied during the lifetime of a1.

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of things it could refer to. The only place I've seen that *precise* wording used much is C99 though.

A flexible array member is the official C99 name for what used to (usually) be called the "struct hack". The basic idea is that you define a struct something like this:

```
struct x {
    int a; // whatever members you want here.
    size_t size;
    int x[]; // no size, last member only
};
```

This is used primarily (or exclusively) with dynamic allocation. When you want to allocate an object of this type, you allocate enough extra space for whatever size of array you need:

```
struct x *a = malloc(sizeof(struct x) + 20 * sizeof(int));
a->size = 20;
```

The `size` member isn't strictly necessary, but often handy to keep track of the size allocated for a item. The one above has space for 20 int's, but the main point of this is that you might have several around, each with its own size.

Comment: Should probably hide the complex `malloc()` call behind a function: `struct x *struct_x_alloc(size_t s) { struct x *t = malloc(sizeof t + s * sizeof(int)); t->size = s; return t; }`

Comment: @Chris: yes, but don't go too far toward making it all manageable, or people will start to mistake it for C++. ;-)

Comment: @Chris: your size calculation is wrong - it should read `sizeof *t + ...`; instead of `sizeof(int)`, you can also use `sizeof *t->x`

Comment: @Christoph - My bad, but it's too late to edit. Yours is wrong also: `sizeof t->x` (I wasn't sure if a dereference was allowed for `sizeof` but I believe it is. Either way, an array size variable _better_ be `size_t`)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't such thing as a flexible array, but there is such thing as a flexible array member.  It is used to provide access to variable-length data as a member of a struct.

From http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/strct.htm:

> A flexible array member, which is a
>   C99 feature, can be an element of a
>   structure with more than one named
>   member. A flexible array member can be
>   used to access a variable-length
>   object. The flexible array member must
>   be the last element of such a
>   structure, and it has incomplete type.

Answer (score 1):

Does this describe what you are asking about?  This is not unique to Sun's C compiler, but it was the first clear overview I found:

[Sun Studio 12 Update 1: C User's Guide: Flexible Array Members](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-7598/6nirjuni7/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Flexible array members are indispensable tools in network programming. In network programming, you never know the data size in advance.

For example, you are writing a code to supply the entire ROUTING TABLE for some reasons. You never know how many routes are there beforehand and allocating maximum supported will hamper your code severely. The safest bet is to declare the flexible array member and cook all your data and fire it once.