# gcc: Forward pointer address with sizeof value

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, struct, malloc

Working with this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int j_btree_create (int fn_initial_nodes);

typedef struct {
    int depth;
    int value;
    void *item;
    void *left_pointer;
    void *right_pointer;
} j_btree_node_int;

typedef struct {
    int nodes;
    int available_nodes;
    int btree_extension;
} j_btree_descriptor_int;



int j_btree_create (int fn_initial_nodes) {
    int *free_btree_node;
    int loop_counter;
    j_btree_descriptor_int *btree_start;

    btree_start = (j_btree_descriptor_int *) malloc (((sizeof(j_btree_node_int) + sizeof(free_btree_node)) * fn_initial_nodes) + sizeof(j_btree_descriptor_int));

    (*btree_start).nodes = fn_initial_nodes;
    (*btree_start).available_nodes = fn_initial_nodes;
    (*btree_start).extension = NULL; */
    for (loop_counter = 0; loop_counter < fn_initial_nodes; loop_counter++) {
        printf ("loop_test: %d", loop_counter);
    }
}
```

I want a pointer that points to the location after the binary tree descriptor (basically a struct at btree_start)

Can I do this with by

```
free_btree_node = btree_start + sizeof(j_btree_descriptor_int);
```

Or is this liable to go completely wrong? If so how should I do this? I will be doing something similar to initially populate the table of unused binary tree nodes.

Comment: "I want a pointer that ... " - why?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to keep it all in one structure, one approach is to use a 'flexible array member':

```
typedef struct {
    int *value;
    j_btree_node_int node;
} j_btree_node;

typedef struct {
    j_btree_descriptor_int btree_start;
    j_btree_node nodes[0];
} j_btree;

j_btree *btree = malloc(sizeof(j_btree) + fn_initial_nodes * sizeof(j_btree_node));
free_btree_node = &j_btree->nodes[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't aware of flexible sized arrays, but a useful tool to be aware of, one I shall do more research into! -Jamie

Comment: I believe they are more commonly called 'flexible array members' so I amended the answer (that should help if you want to search for the term).

Comment: The C99-conformant way to declare a flexible array member is `j_btree_node nodes[];`. The `[0]` is an extension (GNU, I think), that may be supported by fewer compilers than C99.

Comment: This is not valid C; there are no zero-length objects in C. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732901/what-is-a-flexible-array for the correct syntax and usage.

Comment: @DanielFischer, @JimBalter: You are both correct. For ANSI C, one should use `[1]`; for C99, one should use `[]`. Note, though, that the question was tagged `gcc`.

Comment: Just because it was tagged gcc doesn't mean that the OP is asking for an answer in terms of non-portable gcc extensions ... the OP is a novice who doesn't know any better. If you're going to use a non-standard extension in an answer, you should clearly identify it as such and should not use terminology from the C standard ("flexible array member") that refers to different syntax. Also, the C89 solution works in gcc and C99 too.

Comment: I do certainly need my code to portable and as far as possible not reliant on one form of C

Answer (score 1):

You ask about

```
free_btree_node = btree_start + sizeof(j_btree_descriptor_int);
```

Because of the rules of pointer arithmetic, which implicitly multiply an offset by the type's size, that's equivalent to

```
free_btree_node = &btree_start[sizeof(j_btree_descriptor_int)];
```

which isn't what you want. What you want is

```
free_btree_node = (int*)&btree_start[1];
```

or, equivalently,

```
free_btree_node = (int*)(btree_start + 1);
```

Yes, you can do that, since you allocated extra space. But it doesn't really make sense, because you allocated `((sizeof(j_btree_node_int) + sizeof(free_btree_node)) * fn_initial_nodes)` extra bytes, which is not a count of `int`s. It's not clear what you want that to be, but it certainly can't be right because `free_btree_node` is a pointer and you have no interest in its size ... you probably meant `sizeof(*free_btree_node)`. But your code is impenetrable because there are no comments explaining what things are or why you are doing things. In particular, there should be a comment on your malloc saying exactly what it is you think you are allocing ... maybe even a little diagram. Or you could forego trying to allocate contiguous structures and allocate each sort of thing independently.

```
(*btree_start).nodes
```

Please use

```
btree_start->nodes
```

It's standard usage, more succinct, more comprehendible ...

Comment: Thanks for that Jim, I fairly new to dealing with C, so I have ended using some pretty messy methods, and incorrect ones so it seems. It is certainly useful for you to point what you have. Please excuse the lack of comments, although what you have put is still very useful even if you don't know fully the context. This is basically to be used to store a set of file descriptors and keep track of what they do.