# What is the use of nested Structures In C

Tags: c

I am noob Programmer. I don't why we need to go for nesting a structure.
Can you please explain me in detail. please.

Comment: What C book are you using ?

Comment: Sometimes it's helpful to group members according to role..

Comment: Actually, *every* language *trait* of *C* is *useful*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, some buckets in some hashtable (associating string names to integer values) might be

```
 struct bucket_st {
    unsigned len;
    struct {
       char* name;
       int val;
    } ent[];
 };
```

I'm using a [flexible array member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2732989/841108) `ent` in the `bucket_st` structure, and that needs to be a nested `struct` .

Also, if you are coding a 2D application, you probably have a lot of

```
 struct point_st { int x, int y; };
```

and you would define a line segment by the two extremal points:

```
 struct linesegment_st {
    struct point_st p0, p1;
 };
```

Then, if `li` is such a line, you want to speak about `li.p0.x` etc...

Within the POSIX or Linux API, [setitimer(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html) syscall deals with `struct itimerval` which contains other `struct`....

I'm really surprised you have asked about nested structures. You really did not look for them a lot.

Comment: What is Flexible array :/

Comment: added a link, it is actually *flexible array member*

Comment: Why the recent downvote?