# python 3.3 dict: how to convert struct PyDictKeysObject to python class?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, dictionary, ctypes

I am trying to modify Brandon Rhodes code [Routines that examine the internals of a CPython dictionary](https://bitbucket.org/brandon/pycon2010-mighty-dictionary/src/ebd9eb16d203182cb366eb7db23bcd4e806da9f3/figures/_dictinfo.py?at=default) so that it works for CPython 3.3.

I believe I have translated this struct successfully.

```
typedef PyDictKeyEntry *(*dict_lookup_func)
    (PyDictObject *mp, PyObject *key, Py_hash_t hash, PyObject ***value_addr);

struct _dictkeysobject {
    Py_ssize_t dk_refcnt;
    Py_ssize_t dk_size;
    dict_lookup_func dk_lookup;
    Py_ssize_t dk_usable;
    PyDictKeyEntry dk_entries[1];
};
```

I think the following looks good now:

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_ulong, POINTER, cast, py_object, CFUNCTYPE

LOOKUPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(POINTER(PyDictKeyEntry), POINTER(PyDictObject), 
                       py_object, c_ulong, POINTER(POINTER(py_object)))

class PyDictKeysObject(Structure):
"""A key object"""
_fields_ = [
    ('dk_refcnt', c_ssize_t),
    ('dk_size', c_ssize_t),
    ('dk_lookup', LOOKUPFUNC),
    ('dk_usable', c_ssize_t),
    ('dk_entries', PyDictKeyEntry * 1),
]

PyDictKeysObject._dk_entries = PyDictKeysObject.dk_entries
PyDictKeysObject.dk_entries = property(lambda s: 
    cast(s._dk_entries, POINTER(PyDictKeyEntry * s.dk_size))[0])
```

This line of code now works, where `d == {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}`:

```
obj = cast(id(d), POINTER(PyDictObject)).contents  # works!!`
```

Here is my translation from the [C struct](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Include/dictobject.h#l23) PyDictObject:

```
class PyDictObject(Structure):  # an incomplete type
    """A dictionary object."""

def __len__(self):
    """Return the number of dictionary entry slots."""
    pass

def slot_of(self, key):
    """Find and return the slot at which `key` is stored."""
    pass

def slot_map(self):
    """Return a mapping of keys to their integer slot numbers."""
    pass

PyDictObject._fields_ = [
    ('ob_refcnt', c_ssize_t),
    ('ob_type', c_void_p),
    ('ma_used', c_ssize_t),
    ('ma_keys', POINTER(PyDictKeysObject)),
    ('ma_values', POINTER(py_object)),  # points to array of ptrs
]
```

Comment: Note: you could link to [hg.python.org directly](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Objects/dictobject.c#l72). Try `ctypes.CFUNCTYPE` to defined `dict_lookup_func`.

Comment: UPDATE: I have now declared the type of dk_lookup using CFUNCTYPE:

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thank you. I have now declared the type of dk_lookup using CFUNCTYPE. Does dk_entries look right? The C code uses dk_entries[1].

Comment: `type name[1]` as the last member of a struct is a non-portable c89 way to emulate [c99 flexible array member](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2732989/4279). It looks like the pointer type is appropriate here (I'm not sure).

Comment: @eryksun Thanks. This has helped a lot. If I create an instance of PyDictKeysObj I can see the structure (in a debugger). I see dk_entries[0]. I do still have a problem tho. It might be with another struct translation into python: PyDictObject . My code matches the C source exactly. But the following does not work: `obj = cast(id(d), POINTER(PyDictObject)).contents` This line crashes the program.

Comment: @eryksun BTW, I am using a Win64 machine. The line of code 'obj = dictobject(d)` works now. I can see all the keys in the dictionary in the dk_entries array! I deleted d[0] and even see the <dummy> key. dk_entries is the right size. Thank you! I don't understand something about the display of PyDictKeysObject.ma_keys. ma_keys.contents looks good. But at the same level of contents are PyDictKeysObject objects every 8 bytes. The debugger displays up to 10,000 of these objects. Don't know why all this memory has type PyDictKeysObject.

Comment: @eryksun Can you copy and paste your comments in the Answer box so I can accept it? Got all my helper methods to work. Now I can probe the internals of a python 3.3 dictionary and build a dict mapping key inserted to a list of collisions before it found a slot. Purpose? To experiment with the performance of the hashing algorithm used by python. This was my first experience with ctypes module. Thank you a ton.

Comment: @eryksun I wanted to research some of the comments you made. 1. The reason I couldn't define the property in the class itself had to do with the metaclass. Could you repost your comment? 2. You also mentioned an alternative to the property. You mentioned something about "every time I instantiate". Can you repost those comments? Appreciated.

Comment: @eryksun How do I attribute this answer to you? You need to get the reputation points. Could not have done this without your guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was to access the C struct underlying a python dictionary implemented in Cpython 3.3. I started with the C structs provided in cpython/Objects/dictobject.c and Include/dictobject.h . Three C structs are involved in defining the dictionary: PyDictObject, PyDictKeysObject, and PyDictKeyEntry. The correct translation of each C struct into python is as follows. The comments indicate where I needed to make fixes. Thank you to @eryksun for guiding me along the way!!

```
class PyDictKeyEntry(Structure):
"""An entry in a dictionary."""
    _fields_ = [
        ('me_hash', c_ulong),
        ('me_key', py_object),
        ('me_value', py_object),
    ]

class PyDictObject(Structure):
    """A dictionary object."""
    pass

LOOKUPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(POINTER(PyDictKeyEntry), POINTER(PyDictObject), py_object, c_ulong, POINTER(POINTER(py_object)))

class PyDictKeysObject(Structure):
"""An object of key entries."""
    _fields_ = [
        ('dk_refcnt', c_ssize_t),
        ('dk_size', c_ssize_t),
        ('dk_lookup', LOOKUPFUNC),  # a function prototype per docs 
        ('dk_usable', c_ssize_t),
        ('dk_entries', PyDictKeyEntry * 1),  # an array of size 1; size grows as keys are inserted into dictionary; this variable-sized field was the trickiest part to translate into python
    ]   

PyDictObject._fields_ = [
    ('ob_refcnt', c_ssize_t),  # Py_ssize_t translates to c_ssize_t per ctypes docs
    ('ob_type', c_void_p),     # could not find this in the docs
    ('ma_used', c_ssize_t),
    ('ma_keys', POINTER(PyDictKeysObject)),
    ('ma_values', POINTER(py_object)),  # Py_Object* translates to py_object per ctypes docs
]

PyDictKeysObject._dk_entries = PyDictKeysObject.dk_entries
PyDictKeysObject.dk_entries = property(lambda s: cast(s._dk_entries, POINTER(PyDictKeyEntry * s.dk_size))[0])  # this line is called every time the attribute dk_entries is accessed by a PyDictKeyEntry instance; it returns an array of size dk_size starting at address _dk_entries. (POINTER creates a pointer to the entire array; the pointer is dereferenced (using [0]) to return the entire array); the code then accesses the ith element of the array)
```

The following function provides access to the PyDictObject underlying the python dictionary:

```
def dictobject(d):
    """Return the PyDictObject lying behind the Python dict `d`."""
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        raise TypeError('cannot create a dictobject from %r' % (d,))
    return cast(id(d), POINTER(PyDictObject)).contents
```

If d is a python dictionary with key-value pairs, then obj is the PyDictObject instance that contains the key-value pairs:

```
obj = cast(id(d), POINTER(PyDictObject)).contents
```

An instance of the PyDictKeysObject is:

```
key_obj = obj.ma_keys.contents
```

A pointer to the key stored in slot 0 of the dictionary is:

```
key_obj.dk_entries[0].me_key
```

The program that uses these classes, together with routines that probe the hash collisions of each key inserted into a dictionary, is located [here](https://gist.github.com/LeslieK/11196050). My code is a modification of code written by Brandon Rhodes for python 2.x. His code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/brandon/pycon2010-mighty-dictionary/src/f432ae61c5df/figures/_dictinfo.py).

Comment: @eryksun I knew I was confused by "a pointer to an array, the whole array". When I came back to research my confusion I saw your comment and greatly appreciate it. So when we access the attribute dk_entries we are returning the whole array. Why is the struct defined to contain the whole array? [Eli Bendersky comments](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/11/pointers-to-arrays-in-c/): Truly, I can’t imagine why one would use a pointer to an array in real life.

Comment: Eli's examples miss a common case for using `int (*p)[4]`, or alternatively `int p[][4]`, as a parameter. He only looks at `(*p)[2] = 10`, but C here knows that `*p` is an array of 4 `int` values, so `p[1]` adds `4 * sizeof(int)` to the base address. So now we can intuitively handle this as an n x 4 2D array, e.g. `p[1][2] = 10`. C99 even lets us pass in the number of columns as an argument, e.g. `void test(size_t n, size_t m, int p[][m])`.

Comment: *"Why is the struct defined to contain the whole array?"* I haven't studied this in depth. I guess it may improve performance for small dicts; it's allocated in one call in a contiguous block that improves cache locality. But you'd really have to ask someone more familiar with the design...